# Append dynamic query json

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

I am writing a dynamic update statement in sql and I want to append json node in existing json by using json query.

```
   DECLARE @Query NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @TS VARCHAR(50) = 'TS20160101'
SET @Query = 
'UPDATE testtable
SET    metricdata = Json_modify(metricdata, ''$. ' + @TS + '.trend.Value'',
                                        Cast(Json_value(metricdata,
                                        ''$.'+ @TS +'.trend.Value'') AS
                                        FLOAT)
                                                                        + 5),
       AuditTrail = Json_modify(AuditTrail, ''append $.'+ @TS +'.trend'',
                    Json_query(N''{"value":   '+ 'CAST(CAST((CAST(Json_value(metricdata,''$.'+ @TS +'.trend.Value'') AS float) *5) AS float) AS nvarchar(28)) '
                                        +', "ModifiedBy":"Bilal.Asghar@visionet.com", "ModifiedDate": "2022-01-13 10:10:23.447"}''))
WHERE  id IN ( 1, 2, 3 ) '

EXEC (@Query)
```

I have 3 rows in table with Id 1,2,3.
Metric Data rows:

```
{"mape":{"Value":"0","ModifiedBy":"System","ModifiedDate":"2022-01-14 13:55:09.317"},"TS20160101":{"trend":{"Value":9.165000000000000e+003,"ModifiedBy":"System","ModifiedDate":"2022-01-14 13:55:09.317"}}}
{"mape":{"Value":"0","ModifiedBy":"System","ModifiedDate":"2022-01-14 13:55:09.317"},"TS20160101":{"trend":{"Value":9.265000000000000e+003,"ModifiedBy":"System","ModifiedDate":"2022-01-14 13:55:09.317"}}}
{"mape":{"Value":"0","ModifiedBy":"System","ModifiedDate":"2022-01-14 13:55:09.317"},"TS20160101":{"trend":{"Value":9.365000000000000e+003,"ModifiedBy":"System","ModifiedDate":"2022-01-14 13:55:09.317"}}}
```

Audit Trail rows

```
{"TS20160101":{"trend":[{"value":79987,"ModifiedBy":"Systems","ModifiedDate":"2021-09-24 19:21:10.443"},{"value":     100, "ModifiedBy":"Bilal.Asghar@visionet.com", "ModifiedDate": "2022-01-13 10:10:23.447"},{"value":   9.155000000000000e+003, "ModifiedBy":"Bilal.Asghar@visionet.com", "ModifiedDate": "2022-01-13 10:10:23.447"},{"value":   45800, "ModifiedBy":"Bilal.Asghar@visionet.com", "ModifiedDate": "2022-01-13 10:10:23.447"}]}}
{"TS20160101":{"trend":[{"value":79987,"ModifiedBy":"Systems","ModifiedDate":"2021-09-24 19:21:10.443"},{"value":     100, "ModifiedBy":"Bilal.Asghar@visionet.com", "ModifiedDate": "2022-01-13 10:10:23.447"},{"value":   9.255000000000000e+003, "ModifiedBy":"Bilal.Asghar@visionet.com", "ModifiedDate": "2022-01-13 10:10:23.447"},{"value":   46300, "ModifiedBy":"Bilal.Asghar@visionet.com", "ModifiedDate": "2022-01-13 10:10:23.447"}]}}
{"TS20160101":{"trend":[{"value":79987,"ModifiedBy":"Systems","ModifiedDate":"2021-09-24 19:21:10.443"},{"value":     100, "ModifiedBy":"Bilal.Asghar@visionet.com", "ModifiedDate": "2022-01-13 10:10:23.447"},{"value":   9.355000000000000e+003, "ModifiedBy":"Bilal.Asghar@visionet.com", "ModifiedDate": "2022-01-13 10:10:23.447"},{"value":   46800, "ModifiedBy":"Bilal.Asghar@visionet.com", "ModifiedDate": "2022-01-13 10:10:23.447"}]}}
```

I want to modify metric data json and add node in audit trail.
My issue is this in audit trail column its appending node as a string and not calculating value

Comment: You say the above is "dynamic" but there's nothing dynamic about it. You're just concatenating literals. I feel we're missing the "meat" of the problem here.

Comment: What is the actual JSON content, stored in the `metricdata` and `AuditTrail` columns and what is the expected final JSON?

Comment: yes you are right, here some of the keys are dynamic like '$.TS20160101.trend'  which I am passing to my store procedure, I just want to convey my problem here

Comment: I want to modify a json in metricdata and append json object in audittrail

Comment: If you use SQL Server 2017+, you may pass a variable as value of the `path` parameter. And the actual JSON content will help here.

Comment: Considering that the SQL above isn't dynamic, I would suggest moving it into a "normal" statement, that doesn't use `EXEC (@Query)`; there's no need for it. You'll find debugging your SQL much easier then without the added unneeded complication of a deferring statement.

Comment: My some parameters are dynamic as I explained earlier so dynamic sql is my need

Comment: Then show us an actual meaningful/representative version, @Billz . The above is **not** dynamic.

Comment: Question updated with near to real.

Comment: @Billz, thanks and what is the SQL Server version?

Comment: Its Azure SQL...

Comment: Still need to add (to the question, not a comment) an example of the JSON you're reading and exactly how that determines what the final query looks like. We can't solve "I'm trying to use {unknown} to make {known query} look like {unknown}"... also, it might help to start a little bit simpler.

Comment: Again question updated

Answer (score 0):

**Answer:** I don't tnink that you need a dynamic statement here. As is explained in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-modify-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15): *... in SQL Server 2017 (14.x) and in Azure SQL Database, you can provide a variable as the value of path...*. The following statement, based on the attempt from the question is a possible solution:

```
DECLARE @ts nvarchar(max) = N'TS20160101'
UPDATE testtable
SET metricdata = JSON_MODIFY (
       metricdata, 
       '$.' + @ts + '.trend.value',
       TRY_CONVERT(int, JSON_VALUE(MetricData, '$.' + @ts + '.trend.value') * 7)
       ),
    AuditTrail = JSON_MODIFY (
       AuditTrail, 
       'append $.' + @ts + '.trend',
       (
       SELECT 
          TRY_CONVERT(int, JSON_VALUE(MetricData, '$.' + @ts + '.trend.value') * 7) AS [Value],
          '2022-01-13 10:10:23.447' AS [ModifiedDate],
          'Bilal.Asghar@*.com' AS ModifiedBy
       FOR JSON PATH
       ) 
     )
```

**Update:** If the table name is dynamic, you need a dynamic statement:

```
DECLARE @path1 nvarchar(max) = N'$.TS20160101.trend.value'
DECLARE @path2 nvarchar(max) = N'append $.TS20160101.trend'
DECLARE @table sysname = N'testtable'
DECLARE @stmt nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @prms nvarchar(max)

SET @stmt = CONCAT(
   N' UPDATE ', QUOTENAME(@table), 
   N' SET ', 
      N'MetricData = JSON_MODIFY (', 
         N'MetricData, ', 
         N'@path1, ', 
         N'TRY_CONVERT(int, JSON_VALUE(MetricData, @path1) * 7)',
      N'), ',
      N'AuditTrail = JSON_MODIFY (', 
         N'AuditTrail, ', 
         N'@path2, ', 
         N'(',
         N'SELECT ',
            N'TRY_CONVERT(int, JSON_VALUE(MetricData, @path1) * 7) AS [Value], ',
              N'''2022-01-13 10:10:23.447'' AS [ModifiedDate], ',
              N'''Bilal.Asghar@*.com'' AS ModifiedBy ',
            N'FOR JSON PATH ',
         N') ',
      N') '
)
SET @prms = N'@path1 nvarchar(max), @path2 nvarchar(max)'

EXEC sp_executesql @stmt, @prms, @path1, @path2
```

Comment: What if table is dynamic it can be testable1 or testtable2 then I definitely need dynamic query :(

Comment: The above query output is
{"TS20160101":{"trend":[{"value":79987,"ModifiedBy":"Systems","ModifiedDate":"2021-09-24 19:21:10.443"},{"value":     100, "ModifiedBy":"Bilal.Asghar@visionet.com", "ModifiedDate": "2022-01-13 10:10:23.447"},{"value":   9.255000000000000e+003, "ModifiedBy":"Bilal.Asghar@visionet.com", "ModifiedDate": "2022-01-13 10:10:23.447"},{"value":   46300, "ModifiedBy":"Bilal.Asghar@visionet.com", "ModifiedDate": "2022-01-13 10:10:23.447"},[{"ModifiedDate":"2022-01-13 10:10:23.447","ModifiedBy":"Bilal.Asghar@*.com"}]]}}  which is not desired output

Comment: @Billz, then you need a dynamic statement. The answer is updated.

Comment: @Billz, about the wrong results -  I can't find right now an explanation in the documentation, but if I remember correctly the `path` argument is case-senstivie. Example `SELECT JSON_VALUE('{"Value": 1}', '$.value')` vs. `SELECT JSON_VALUE('{"Value": 1}', '$.Value')`. So it really depends on the parsed JSON - there are `value` and `Value` keys in your test data.